# Python: How to check if adding/subtracting two 8 bit integers causes a carry or a borrow?

Tags: python, binary, integer, addition

My question is as the title says: How to check if adding/subtracting two 8 bit integers causes a carry or a borrow?

Thanks!

Comment: Add/subtract them and check if the result is more than 255 or less than 0.

Comment: What kind of carry/borrow? Signed or unsigned?

Comment: @Ouroborus both cases for working with signed and unsigned integers

Comment: @kamkow1 Sorry, those were two different questions. What kind of carry? Any bit or just when it would cause an overflow for an 8-bit value?

Comment: @Ouroborus any bit

Comment: For addition, it'd be `(x & y)`. Having the same bit set in both values causes one or more bit-wise carries. When you `&` two values together, and the results are not `0`, then there were matching set bits and therefore a carry would happen. Subtraction is just addition but with the right-hand value's sign flipped, so `(x & -y)`. (This is a comment, not an answer, because I'm not sure how negative numbers might work without putting in more effort.)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for the carry flag and addition is that if you're adding two values c = a + b, then the carry flag is set if c < a when everything is treated as an unsigned value.  Likewise for c = a - b, the carry flag is set if c > a.